# Find the number of return calls that were done by customer care within 30 minutes of the missed call

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a customer care center which receives calls from customers, Starttime and Endtime denotes the conversation start time and end time. Missed calls are the calls where no conversation happened. For any missed call, the customer care returns the call.

For below given table,

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerCare (fromnumber INT, tonumber INT, starttime DATETIME,endtime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO CustomerCare (fromnumber,tonumber,starttime,endtime) 
VALUES
(100,1800,'2019-08-13 18:40:00','2019-08-13 18:40:00'),
(1800,100,'2019-08-13 18:55:00','2019-08-13 18:57:00'),
(200,1800,'2019-08-13 19:30:00','2019-08-13 19:30:00'),
(1800,200,'2019-08-13 20:05:00','2019-08-13 20:10:00'),
(300,1800,'2019-08-13 21:00:00','2019-08-13 21:00:00'),
(1800,300,'2019-08-13 21:20:00','2019-08-13 21:25:00'),
(400,1800,'2019-08-13 07:00:00','2019-08-13 07:00:00'),
(500,1800,'2019-08-13 8:00:00','2019-08-13 8:05:00')
```

[image]

Find the number of return calls that were done by customer care within 30 minutes of the missed call.

Fourth row indicates one such return call.

Can anyone help a SQL query.

Comment: 4th row seems like the return call is didn't make within 30 minutes of the missed call. The missed call is at 19:30 and the return call is at 20:05?

Comment: you want `within 30 mins` or `not within 30 mins` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Umair Ramzan...
Lets consider greater than or equel to 30 Minutes.
Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you find the missed call, then you find the call back by customercare. And you find the time different

```
select  *
from    CustomerCare mc
        cross apply -- get call back time
        (   
            select  top 1 *
            from    CustomerCare x
            where   x.fromnumber    = mc.tonumber
            and     x.tonumber  = mc.fromnumber
            and     x.starttime > mc.starttime
            order by x.starttime
        ) cb
where   mc.starttime = mc.endtime  -- missed call
and     datediff(minute, mc.starttime, cb.starttime) > 30 -- time different between 
                                                          -- missed call and callback
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Squirrel.

How can it looks if we dont use CROSS APPLY..
Any Way to do it..

Comment: what is the reason for that ?

Comment: I am not much aware of cross apply.
This is works for me..
But still...

Comment: if not mistaken, `CROSS APPLY` is introduced since `SQL Server 2005`, it has been more than 10 years. It is not a new feature. You are missing out a lot if you don't use that

Comment: yeah.. Got it @Squirrel.. I figured it out it as similar to INNER JOIN... Thanks by the way..Kudos

Answer (score 1):

@Squirrel beat me to it and my answer *original* answer was basically identical to his but I'll post what I put together as it also speaks to why APPLY is so excellent.

First, for optimal performance you would want a clustered index (or a covering index) on starttime. E.g.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CL_CustomerCare_starttime ON dbo.CustomerCare(starttime);
```

Next, here's how you would do this using a JOIN (since you mentioned it):

```
SELECT 
  cc.fromnumber,
  cc.tonumber, 
  missedcalltime = CAST(CAST(cc.starttime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5)),
  callbacktime   = CAST(CAST(x.starttime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5)),
  timetocallback = datediff(minute, cc.starttime, x.starttime)
FROM   dbo.CustomerCare AS cc
JOIN   dbo.CustomerCare AS x
  ON   cc.tonumber = x.fromnumber
 AND   x.tonumber  = cc.fromnumber
 AND   cc.starttime < x.starttime
WHERE datediff(minute, cc.starttime, x.starttime) <= 30;
```

Now, the APPLY version (this is what I put together before I saw Squirrels answer):

```
SELECT 
  cc.fromnumber,
  cc.tonumber, 
  missedcalltime = CAST(CAST(cc.starttime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5)),
  callbacktime   = CAST(CAST(x.starttime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5)),
  timetocallback = cb.t
FROM   dbo.CustomerCare AS cc
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP (1) x.starttime
  FROM     dbo.CustomerCare AS x
  WHERE    cc.tonumber = x.fromnumber
  AND      x.tonumber  = cc.fromnumber
  AND      cc.starttime < x.starttime
  ORDER BY x.starttime
) AS x
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(datediff(minute, cc.starttime, x.starttime))) AS cb(t)
WHERE       cb.t <= @callback;
```

**Both Return:**

```
fromnumber  tonumber    missedcalltime callbacktime timetocallback
----------- ----------- -------------- ------------ --------------
100         1800        18:40          18:55        15
300         1800        21:00          21:20        20
```

The first cool thing about APPLY is how I can use it to alias values to make my code "DRYer." (DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself). Since the expression `datediff(minute, cc.starttime, x.starttime)` is used multiple times, I can use APPLY to process the expression once then reference it multiple times as **cb.t**. Note the line:

```
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(datediff(minute, cc.starttime, x.starttime))) AS cb(t)
```

This is an example of how APPLY can make your code much cleaner and easier to debug.

The second and possibly more important example of how the powerful of APPLY is how you can join an outer query with a subquery. My two examples above are not Identical. Theoretically, if there were more than one "call back" within 30 minutes, the JOIN version would return them. Since this is likely an edge case, asking for the "TOP (1)" returned call within a half hour will be sufficient and will perform better. If you examine the execution plan for both queries - the join version reads more rows (28) when it self joints to CustomerCare, the APPLY version reads 22 rows. If you change TOP (1) to TOP ([anything greater than 1]) in the APPLY version it will read 28 rows. Again, this is another way you can use APPLY to tune performance.

Lastly, an important note about TOP in a subquery... If you remove the ORDER BY in the APPLY subquery the subquery will read 58 rows instead of 22 when an ORDER BY over a correctly indexed column is present.

Answer (score 0):

```
select B.*
    , B.starttime - A.starttime
    , extract(minute from B.starttime - A.starttime) as callbacktime
from (
    select fromnumber, tonumber, starttime
    from test_customercare
    where starttime = endtime
) A, test_customercare B
where A.tonumber = B.fromnumber
    and A.fromnumber = B.tonumber 
    and extract(minute from B.starttime - A.starttime) < 30
```

here A is the table which holds missed calls…

Comment: This 4-year-old question already has two correct answers - one of which is accepted. This answer has several problems. The question is for SQL Server (T-SQL), but this answer uses the extract() function that is not available in SQL Server. The answer fails to select the *nearest* following return call, if there is more than one. (That is why the other answers use `cross apply`.)  The query also uses old-style-joins. Nobody should be teaching or promoting old-style-joins nowadays. I recommend that this answer be deleted.